# How to put json data with good format in python

Tags: python, json, linux, api

I have 2 issues in my python code. I am trying to get information from weather API. I can do it in this way:

```
[
    {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}
    {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}
]
```

But I need to put a commas between different dictionaries, like this

```
[
    {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"},
    {"key1": "value", "key2": "value"}
]
```

How could I modify my code for it?Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import os
import requests
import json

def getting_weather():
    api_key = 'XXXXXXX'
    cities = ['paris', 'london', 'washington']

    filepath = 'app/raw_files'
    if os.path.exists(filepath) == False:
        os.makedirs(filepath, mode = 511, exist_ok= False)

    os.chdir(filepath)

    json_cities = []

    for city_name in cities:
        r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}&appid={API_key}'.format(city_name=city_name,API_key=api_key))
    
        filename = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')+'.json'
        output = '{text}'.format(text=r.json())
        json_cities.append(output)
        with open(filename, 'a') as file:
            file.write(output)

getting_weather()
```

My second difficulties is to reed this json information. I got an error that path /app/raw_files doesn't exit, I cheked of course, and I do have this path and new file.

```
def transform_data_into_csv(n_files=None, filename='data.csv'):
    parent_folder = '/app/raw_files'
    files = sorted(os.listdir(parent_folder), reverse=True)
    if n_files:
        files = files[:n_files]

    dfs = []

    for f in files:
        with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, f), 'r') as file:
            data_temp = json.load(file)
        for data_city in data_temp:
            dfs.append(
                {
                    'temperature': data_city['main']['temp'],
                    'city': data_city['name'],
                    'pression': data_city['main']['pressure'],
                    'date': f.split('.')[0]
                }
            )

    df = pd.DataFrame(dfs)

    print('\n', df.head(10))

    df.to_csv(os.path.join('/app/clean_data', filename), index=False)

transform_data_into_csv(n_files=20, filename='data.csv')
```

[image]

Thank u for reading my long code. If you need more information I will add.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat your list of strings like the json your variable suggests it is and dump it.

```
json_cities = []

for city_name in cities:
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city_name}&appid={API_key}'.format(city_name=city_name,API_key=api_key))

    filename = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')+'.json'
    output = r.json()
    json_cities.append(output)


with open(filename, 'a') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(json_cities))
```

Comment: I put the way u write, perfect, it works, thank u a lot

Comment: Maybe you can help me please with the second part of the question also. I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/new.py", line 57, in <module>
    transform_data_into_csv(n_files=20, filename='data.csv')
  File "/home/ubuntu/new.py", line 32, in transform_data_into_csv
    files = sorted(os.listdir(parent_folder), reverse=True)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/raw_files'

Comment: @Anastasia_data - If you have seperate questions you should raise it as a seperate question